# Pytest fixtures are not meant to be called directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I would like to set up a fixture in conftest.py and share it with all my tests. However, I run into the following error when running pytest on the following minimal example:

```
ERROR at setup of test_test 
Fixture "pytest_runtest_setup" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,
but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters.
```

`conftest.py`

```
import pytest
import os


@pytest.fixture
def pytest_runtest_setup():
    print("hello ? ---------------------------------")
```

`test.py`

```
import pytest


def test_test():
    assert True
```

`pytest.ini`

```
[pytest]
addopts = -rA -v -p no:faulthandler -W ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

Pytest launched with `pytest test.py`

Nowhere is the fixture function called directly, it is not even used in the sample test. So why is pytest throwing this and how can I declare and use fixtures into conftest.py?

Env:

- Python 3.8.3
- pytest-6.1.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the fixture is `pytest_runtest_setup`, which is actually a [hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_setup) that you override, and is being

> Called to perform the setup phase for a test item.

So it *is* called directly.

Pytest 6 doesn't support [calling `fixture`s directly](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly)

> Removed in version 4.0.
>
> Calling a fixture function directly, as opposed to request them in a
> test function, is deprecated.

Rename the fixture to `runtest_setup` or anything else as long as the `fixture` name doesn't start with `pytest_` when in `conftest.py` or it will be recognized as a hook (there is no issue with the name when located in the test file).

Comment: The "or anything else" rule for fixture names doesn't seem to be correct. I tried to rename my global fixture to `pytest_setup_logging` and got the error `unknown hook 'pytest_setup_logging'` on executing the tests. Thus is assume the `pytest` prefix should be avoided for fixtures.

Comment: @dpr you are correct, you can't name the fixture `pytest_*` in `conftest.py`. It will be ok in any other file though. I added that to the answer.